# Can a Windows 2003 Active Directory server act as a NTP server?

Tags: ntp

Within our LAN, there are two Windows 2003 servers with the Active Directory role. Both these servers have the time service configured to query NTP servers on the internet for the accurate time. That works fine.

I've just installed XenServer v5.6 and it's asked me for the IP address of an NTP server. Without tweaking the firewall, I cannot configure this server to reference an internet based NTP server.

But can I configure it to use the IP address of the internal AD servers, i.e. do AD servers also act as NTP servers to other computers?

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory servers act as NTP servers per default. 
You can specify them as NTP targets for your XenServer

Comment: Smashing thanks, works a treat. That sounds like eBay feedback :-)